footer content bunched together when using bootstrap
the issue is that on only one page that has bootstrap applied to it, my footer content gets bunched together with no space between items whereas my other pages that have the same footer are having proper spacing that's expected.
i have tried to move the css rules from my imported css file to my main css file and then by applying display:flex and playing around with margins i managed to make it look more desirable but it doesnt seem like an efficient solution to me and it makes my code dirty and confusing. any suggestions on what i should do instead to take care of this problem since the css styling file for footer is shared among 5 other pages?
this is my initial css:
  footer {
  z-index: -2;
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  color: #ddd;
  direction: rtl;
}
  #footer-info-section {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row-reverse wrap;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: start;
}
  .footer-info-containers {
  width: 25%;
}

heres the html:
<footer>
  <div id="footer-info-section">
    <div class="footer-info-containers">
     content
    </div>
    <div class="footer-info-containers"> 
     content
    </div>
    <div class="footer-info-containers">
     content
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>

this is what it's supposed to look like( and also how it's displayed on other pages):


this is what it looks like:


can you provide an image of what it should look like and another of what does look like ?

absolutely, it's updated. @Mohammadsiabbou

Make sure you put your styles after importing bootstrap and override its styles, bootstrap applies styles on HTML like p, hr... your only solution is to override them.

@Mohammadsiabbou It is linked to my html in an order that is overriding my bootstrap, but idk why this is happening setting margins and paddings will solve the issue but im afraid its not the best practice
